# Display posts of specific category term

Tags: posts, categories, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I'm using this code to first display each category term as headlines and then display a post which is assigned each category term under the headline.

If I create a custom taxonomy it works as intended, but if I attempt to use the default category taxonomy, the headlines display as intended, but under each headline, it displays every article without regard to the assigned term.  I don't understand why would it work for my custom taxonomy but not for the default category taxonomy.

```
<?php $args = array (
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

$terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;

    $post_args = array (
        'category' => $term->name,
        'posts_per_page'   => '1',
        'no_found_rows' => true
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php }
}
```

If I change it to use my custom taxonomy named 'article_subjects' in this example, everything works as intended.

```
<?php $args = array (
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

$terms = get_terms( 'article_subjects', $args );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;

    $post_args = array (
        'article_subjects' => $term->name,
        'posts_per_page'   => '1',
        'no_found_rows' => true
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php }
}
```

And just in case it's pertinant, here is the code I used to generate the custom taxonomy.

```
function article_subjects() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Subjects', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'dc' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Subject', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'dc' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Subjects', 'dc' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'dc' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'dc' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'dc' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Subject', 'dc' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'dc' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'dc' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'dc' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'dc' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'dc' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'dc' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'dc' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'dc' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'has_archive'                => true,
    'can_export'                 => true

);
register_taxonomy( 'article_subjects', array( 'post' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'article_subjects', 0 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line of code in your first piece of code

```
'category' => $term->name,
```

There are two problems here, first of all, `category` is not a valid parameter for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you should use `category_name`, as you are working with [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). `get_terms` does not return the ID like [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), which is an alternative for the first part of code. Secondly, If you use `category_name`, remember, this is the slug of the category, **not the category name**

So replace

```
'category' => $term->name,
```

with

```
'category_name' => $term->slug,
```

As said, you can also use `get_categories`, so you can do something like this as well

```
<?php $args = array (
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category->name;

    $post_args = array (
        'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
        'posts_per_page'   => '1',
   );

    $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

?>
```

Just to point out, you are passing a few invalid arguments to [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). Please go and check the codex for valid arguments

**EDIT**

From your comments, I think you are missing the closing `endif;` To display [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), your code will look like this

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
  the_post_thumbnail();
endif;
```

Just one more thing I forgot to mention yesterday, you should always reset the postdata ([`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata))when you use a custom query

Comment: Thanks.  Would there be any reason why I can't display the featured_image with this?  Since I corrected the code as you suggested, I haven't been able to get the featured images to display.  Just using      if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail(); inside  while ($query->have_posts())

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: I already took care of it before I saw your reply but thank you very much for taking the time to reply.